# Riemann prime counting function / Log Integral

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I include the beginnings of an investigation:

$$\text{A plot of R}(x)\text{ against }\pi(x):$$

[image]

$$\text{A plot of li}(x)\text{ against }\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{\pi(x^{1/n})}{n}:$$

[image]

It seems as though both are asymptotically similar. The latter seems to avoid any infinite sum involving $\mu(x)$. Is this worth pursuing?

According to [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html), $$\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor\log(x)\rfloor}\frac{\pi(x^{1/n})}{n}$$ was considered by Riemann, but not $$\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{\pi(x^{1/n})}{n}.$$

Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: What is $R(x)$?

Comment: Note that $\pi(x^{1/n})=0$ for $n>(\log x)/\log 2$. So there's not much difference between the two sums. (And I suspect the upper bound in the first one really should be $\lfloor(\log x)/\log 2\rfloor$ anyway. Indeed, checking the other page, I see they use the function lg $x$, which is defined to be the base-2 logarithm, rather than the $\log x$ you wrote.)

Comment: You are quite right- makes sense now- still,  nice insight into this family of functions :)